# SQL Server: Replicated transactions are waiting for the next Log back up or for mirroring partner to catch up

Tags: sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

I have two SQL Server DB instances on the same machine with one hosting a replica of the other. In addition, I have transaction replication setup for all tables on the main instance to the replica. I have verified that the log reader and associated agents are all running. However, one of the log reader agent says "Replicated transactions are waiting for the next Log back up or for mirroring partner to catch up". I have done a transactional log backup to trigger it but to no avail; tried deleting the subscriber and publisher and recreating it again…but still end up with this message.

Comment: Enable `trace flag 1448` and you should be good. This tells sql server `Enables the replication log reader to move forward even if the async secondaries have not acknowledged the reception of a change.`  you can use `dbcc traceon (1448, -1)` globally. And then when you have an outage window, add it as start up parameter.